# How to show an Image in a label with a click event (Memory Game)

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to make a memory game but the code gives a error when labels are clicked on and I need one side to be colored and to show an image when clicked on.

This is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Memory
{
    public partial class frmMain : Form
    {
        Random random = new Random();

        //images
        List<Image> icons = new List<Image>()
        {
        Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\thomas\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Memory\Resources\apple.png"),
        Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\thomas\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Memory\Resources\apple.png"),
        Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\thomas\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Memory\Resources\bananas.png"),
        Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\thomas\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Memory\Resources\bananas.png"),
        Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\thomas\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Memory\Resources\grapes.png"),
        Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\thomas\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Memory\Resources\grapes.png"),
        Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\thomas\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Memory\Resources\kokosnoot.png"),
        Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\thomas\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Memory\Resources\kokosnoot.png"),
        Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\thomas\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Memory\Resources\lemon.png"),
        Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\thomas\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Memory\Resources\lemon.png"),
        Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\thomas\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Memory\Resources\orange.png"),
        Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\thomas\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Memory\Resources\orange.png"),
        Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\thomas\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Memory\Resources\peach.png"),
        Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\thomas\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Memory\Resources\peach.png"),
        Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\thomas\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Memory\Resources\pear.png"),
        Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\thomas\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Memory\Resources\pear.png"),
        Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\thomas\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Memory\Resources\pepper.png"),
        Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\thomas\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Memory\Resources\pepper.png"),
        Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\thomas\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Memory\Resources\pineapple.png"),
        Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\thomas\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Memory\Resources\pineapple.png"),
        Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\thomas\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Memory\Resources\strawberry.png"),
        Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\thomas\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Memory\Resources\strawberry.png"),
        Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\thomas\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Memory\Resources\watermelon.png"),
        Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\thomas\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Memory\Resources\watermelon.png"),
        };

        //pictures to labels
        public void AssignPicsToLabels()
        {
            foreach (Control control in tableLayoutPanel1.Controls)
            {
                Label iconLabel = control as Label;
                if (iconLabel != null)
                {
                    int randomNumber = random.Next(icons.Count);
                    iconLabel.Image = icons[randomNumber];
                    icons.RemoveAt(randomNumber);
                }
            }
        }

        public frmMain()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            AssignPicsToLabels();
        }

        //Images randomizing
        private void RandomizeImages()
        {
            Shuffle(icons);
            int Index = 0;

            foreach (Control control in tableLayoutPanel1.Controls)
            {
                var imageLabel = control as Label;
                if (imageLabel == null)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                imageLabel.Tag = Index;
                Index++;
            }
        }

        private static Random rng = new Random();

        private static void Shuffle<T>(List<T> list)
        {
            int count = list.Count;
            while (count > 1)
            {
                count--;
                int L = rng.Next(count + 1);
                T value = list[L];
                list[L] = list[count];
                list[count] = value;
            }
        }

        private void label_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Label clickedLabel = sender as Label;

            if (clickedLabel != null)
            {
                var Index = (int)clickedLabel.Tag;
                clickedLabel.Image = icons[Index];

                clickedLabel.ForeColor = Color.Black;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It gives an error here:

```
var Index = (int)clickedLabel.Tag
```

Comment: Well, it is not possible to cast `string` to `int` just with help of explicit cast `(int)str` because the `string` is *not* an `int`. You could use `Convert.ToInt32("")` instead

Comment: I did it like this: 'var Index = Convert.ToInt32(clickedLabel.Tag);' didn't work

Comment: You doesn't seem to use `RandomizeImages` method which associates index with label tag. Instead, you use `AssignPicsToLabels` which is doing something different and also destroys the `icons` list.

Comment: @Fabjan This is not VB6, `Control.Tag` property type is `object`.

Comment: Index is defined inside method RandomizeImages().  Move Index to global space.   Try commenting out the ForeColor = color.Black and see what happens.  Also sometimes setting image = null and then to your image will update the form and correct issue.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues here - the Tag property is actually set to an integer (contrary to some comments) but only if `RandomizeImages` is actually called, which it doesn't seem to be as the shuffling is actually done in `AssignPicsToLabels`, otherwise the Tag property will be null which is probably causing your error.

I think you'll get the behaviour you want if you delete `RandomizeImages` altogether and replace `AssignPicsToLabels` with the following :

```
//pictures to labels
public void AssignPicsToLabels()
{
    var iconIndices = Enumerable.Range(0, icons.Count-1).ToList();
    Shuffle(iconIndices);
    int nIcon = 0;

    foreach (Control control in tableLayoutPanel1.Controls)
    {
        Label iconLabel = control as Label;
        if (iconLabel != null)
        {
            // TODO - check for array out of bounds
            iconLabel.Tag = iconIndices[nIcon++];
        }
    }
}
```

This will give each label a random and unique integer image index in the Tag property which should then give the expected results in the click handler.  You may also want to replace the icons member list with a static array since this list will no longer itself be modified.

Comment: this line: 'Enumerable.Range(0, icons.Count - 1).ToList();' says now: 'Operator - cannot be applied to operands of type method group and int' i made the array an Image array

Comment: Sorry, please change .Count to .Length now it is an array

Comment: Thanks. But now the line: iconLabel.Tag = iconIndices[nIcon++]; says: An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Comment: Sorry, my bad - I though Enumerable.Range was inclusive.  Change to Enumerable.Range(0, icons.Length);  (i.e. lose the -1).

Comment: Okay thanks but ForeColor doesn't work to cover the images. If you want to help with that real quick, thanks